# Django Middleware keeps redirecting, visiting admin-site not possible

Tags: django, django-urls, django-middleware

I followed a Django tutorial and wrote a Middleware class, to be precise its a "Login-Required"-Middleware so Users are just allowed to do some things on the website when they are logged in.

The problem is that the middleware works as it should be but I can not visit the Django-Admin website anymore. Even after adding the admin-url to the exception list. He keeps redirecting me to the "normal login site".

This is my middleware

```
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.urls import reverse


EXEMPT_URLS = [re.compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [re.compile(url) for url in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]

class LoginRequiredMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
        print (path)

        # if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        #     if not any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS):
        #         return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)

        url_is_exempt = any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS)

        if path == reverse('logout').lstrip('/'):
            logout(request)

        if request.user.is_authenticated() and url_is_exempt:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

        elif request.user.is_authenticated() or url_is_exempt:
            return None

        else:
                return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

This is the Login_EXEMPT_URLS in settings.py

```
LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = (
r'^admin/',
r'^kalender/login/$',
r'^kalender/logout/$',
r'^kalender/reset-password/$',
r'^kalender/reset-password/done/$',
r'^kalender/reset-password/complete/$',
r'^kalender/reset-password/$',
r'^kalender/reset-password/confirm/',
r'^kalender/returnjson/'
)

LOGIN_URL = '/kalender/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/kalender/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/kalender/'
ADMIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/admin/'
```

This is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'kalender/login.html'}, name='login'),
    #url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name': 'kalender/login.html'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^delete/$', views.delete, name='delete'),
    url(r'^delete2/$', views.delete2, name='delete2'),
    url(r'^addTimestamp/$', views.addTimestamp, name='addTimestamp'),
    url(r'^delete_many/$', views.delete_many, name='delete_many'),
    url(r'^add_many/$', views.add_many, name='add_many'),
    url(r'^addPT/$', views.addPT, name='addPT'),
    url(r'^deletePT/$', views.deletePT, name='deletePT'),
    url(r'^settings/$', views.edit_settings, name='edit_settings'),
    url(r'^nextMonth/$', views.nextMonth, name='nextMonth'),
    url(r'^previousMonth/$', views.previousMonth, name='previousMonth'),
    url(r'^view_profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    url(r'^edit_profile/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    url(r'^change_postbox/$', views.change_postbox, name='change_postbox'),
    url(r'^getNextTimestamp/$', views.getNextTimestamp, name='getNextTimestamp'),
    url(r'^returnjson/$', views.returnjson, name='returnjson'),
    url(r'^change-password$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    url(r'^reset-password/$', password_reset, {'template_name': 'kalender/reset_password.html'}, name='reset_password'),
    url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done, {'template_name': 'kalender/reset_password_done.html'}, name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', password_reset_confirm, {'template_name': 'kalender/reset_password_formular.html'}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset-password/complete/$', password_reset_complete, {'template_name': 'kalender/reset_password_complete.html'}, name='password_reset_complete'),
    #url(r'sendEmail/^$', views.sendEmail, name='sendEmail'),
]
```

EDIT: Thanks to the help i got here, i now can login to the admin page, but as soon as i login, i get redirected to my home view via the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL. But I want to keep proceeding to the admin page after login. How do i do that? You can see the redirects here: (the output of the console in Pycharm)

```
admin/
[21/May/2018 13:11:38] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
admin/login/
[21/May/2018 13:11:38] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1668
admin/login/
[21/May/2018 13:11:44] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
admin/
[21/May/2018 13:11:44] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
kalender/
```

Comment: Since you are already removing the leading slash in your middleware, you could remove `r'^/admin/$'` and `r'^/admin/login/?next=/admin/$'` since they are never going to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password reset confirm url is something like `kalender/reset-password/confirm/abc-123/`. None of your regexes match that. You need to add something like `r'^kalender/reset-password/confirm/'`

Comment: Thanks your advice helped. Now i just need to get this done for the django admin site. As you see I already added the URLs but he still redirects me to the login page when I try to open the admin site.

Comment: `r'^admin/$'` will only match `admin/` (because of the dollar). If you use `r'^admin/'` instead, it will match `admin/` and other urls like `admin/something/else/`.

Comment: Damn, I tried so many things for hours and it didnt work because of that single dollar symbol. Thank you very much. I would like to mark your answer as useful but i cant since my account is new.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't worry about it - you'll be able to upvote other questions/answers once you've got a bit more reputation.

Comment: Hello @Alasdair,
I think i rushed the things a little. Didnt work on the project for more than a month. There is still one problem left. I can now visit the admin site, but i after I login with admin credentials, i am still getting redirected to my home view. I editted the post. Can you please help me out again? Thanks in advance

Comment: That sounds like a different issue, so you would be better to ask a new question -- this question is marked as accepted so it isn't going to get any attention. Looking briefly at your question, I don't understand why you are doing `if request.user.is_authenticated() and url_is_exempt:`. Also, when you do `redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)`, you aren't including any information about where you are redirecting from (e.g. `?next=/current-url/`, so the user won't be redirected back to the original page after logging in.